# Incompatibility between time.sleep() and pysimplegui.Output()?

Tags: python, time, output, sleep, pysimplegui

I am currently implementing a chess game in Python using pysimplegui. As you can see on the picture, in the left part there is the chess board, and in the right part you have some buttons and an output area that displays some messages related to the game and the buttons. In particular, I would like to have a message displayed when I click the button "QUIT" saying "We quit :(" followed by a delay of a few seconds so that the player can see the message before the window actually closes. The code for that action is the following:

```
if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'QUIT':
  print('We quit :(')
  time.sleep(2)
  break
```

The problem is that there is actually a pause of 2 seconds between the moment where I click the button "QUIT" and the moment where the message is displayed so that the window closes right after the message, which is useless. It is like the position of the print and the time.sleep had been reversed. Now, if I disable the output area, and that the message is displayed in a regular terminal the behavior is the one expected: the message is displayed followed by a two seconds pause and then the chess window closes. For information, the code of the output area in the right part is:

```
sg.Output(size=(72,37), font=('Verdana',12), \
background_color='white', key='-OUTPUT-')
```

My question is then the following: is there some incompatibility between time.sleep() and pysimplegui, and in particular sg.Output? Did I do something wrong? Is there a way to fix that behavior? Any suggestion is welcome.

[image: picture chess board]

Comment: Add one statement `window.refresh()` after your `print` and before your `sleep` to update the GUI immediately, or it will be updated until next `read`.

Comment: Thank you Jason Yang, now it has exactly the behavior I was expecting. And your answer also helped understand what was the problem

Comment: Newer versions of PySimpleGUI won't have this problem.  The `Output` element now has an "auto-refresh" set so that the window is automatically refreshed after a print.  You'll need to upgrade to the version of PySimpleGUI on GitHub.  The change has not yet been relesaed to PyPI.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make the functionality you need using threads. I can't explain why the execution sequence is broken, probably it has something to do with redirecting the output stream.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
import threading


def long_function_thread(window):
    time.sleep(3)
    window.write_event_value('-THREAD DONE-', '')

def long_function():
    threading.Thread(target=long_function_thread, args=(window,), daemon=True).start()


layout = [[sg.Output(size=(60,10))],
          [sg.Button('QUIT')]]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

while True:             # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event == 'QUIT':
        print('We quit :(')
        long_function()

    elif event == '-THREAD DONE-':
        break
    else:
        print(event, values)
window.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Сергей Кох for taking the time to answer my question and building up a minimal example. Jason Yang in his comment above proposed a simple fix, and as I was looking for the simplest solution, I used his solution.